# Oracle - From WebFocus to Oracle - Sum with case

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, case

I have an ETL that was created in WebFocus, and will migrate it to Oracle.

I would like an alternative to the following situations. In WebFocus, he can use a previous calculated  column, as a parameter to calculate another value.

Example:

```
SUM(CASE
   WHEN T1.M2143831 > T1.M2460254
     THEN
       (T1.M2143831 * 100 / T1.M2143833)
     ELSE
       (T1.M2460254 * 100 / T1.M2460256)
END) AS TAXA_L,
SUM(CASE
   WHEN T4.FABR_ID = 'TEST'
        AND TAX_L >= 80
     THEN  1
   ELSE NULL
END) OVER80
```

As an example, it uses the **TAX_L** calculated in the previous step, as a parameter for second *case*, and Oracle can not do this.
I tried as follows:

```
SUM(CASE
      WHEN T4.FABR_ID = 'TEST'
         AND SUM(CASE
                    WHEN T1.M2143831 > T1.M2460254
                    THEN
                        (T1.M2143831 * 100 / T1.M2143833)
                    ELSE
                        (T1.M2460254 * 100 / T1.M2460256)
                 END) >= 80
      THEN
         1
      ELSE
         NULL
END)AS OVER80
```

But I received the following error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Any alternative to this case?

**--- Part of Original query / WebFocus**

```
  SELECT   T4.FABR_ID,
           T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME,
           T3.DAY_OF_WEEK,
           T4.REGIONAL_ID,
           T4.UF_ID,
           T4.BSC_ID,
           T2.COD_IBGE,
           T4.BTS_ID,
           SUM (T1.M2251827) AS CAP_ALLOC,
           SUM(CASE
                  WHEN T1.M2143831 > T1.M2460254
                  THEN
                     (T1.M2143831 * 100 / T1.M2143833)
                  ELSE
                     (T1.M2460254 * 100 / T1.M2460256)
               END)
              AS TAX_L,
           SUM (100 * T1.M2489212 / T1.M2489213) AS IUB_FRAME_LOST,
           SUM (T1.M1979632 * T1.M1979630) AS NUM_ACE,
           SUM (T1.M1977785 * T1.M1973189) AS DEN_ACE,
           SUM (T1.M2225994) AS THROUGHPUT_IUB_DOWNLINK_E,
           SUM(  (T1.M2016166 + T1.M2016172 + T1.M1978319 + T1.M1978331)
               * 8
               / 3600)
              AS THROUGHPUT_DADOS_TOTAL_H,
           SUM(CASE
                  WHEN T4.FABR_ID = 'TEST'
                       AND TAX_L >= 80
                  THEN
                     1
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END)
              AS OVER80,
           SUM(CASE
                  WHEN     T4.FABR_ID = 'TEST'
                       AND TAX_L < 80
                       AND TAX_L IS NOT NULL
                  THEN
                     1
                  ELSE
                     NULL
               END)
              AS OVER80
    FROM   DBN1.F_BTS T1,
           DBN1.DA_CADASTRO T2,
           DBN1.D_TIME T3,
           DBN1.D_ENTITY_BTS T4
   WHERE       (T2.AA_CADASTRO_KEY = T1.AA_CADASTRO_KEY)
           AND (T3.TIME_KEY = T1.TIME_KEY)
           AND (T4.ENTITY_KEY = T1.ENTITY_KEY)
           AND (T2.COD_IBGE <> -1)
           AND (T3.HOUR BETWEEN 08 AND 23)
           AND (T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE ('27-09-2016 08:00:00',
                                                     'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                                        AND  TO_DATE ('27-09-2016 23:59:59',
                                                      'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
           AND (T4.FABR_ID IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2'))
           AND (T4.BTS_ID NOT IN ('', '*, -1'))
GROUP BY   T4.FABR_ID,
           T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME,
           T3.DAY_OF_WEEK,
           T4.REGIONAL_ID,
           T4.UF_ID,
           T4.BSC_ID,
           T2.COD_IBGE,
           T4.BTS_ID
ORDER BY   T4.FABR_ID,
           T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME,
           T3.DAY_OF_WEEK,
           T4.REGIONAL_ID,
           T4.UF_ID,
           T4.BSC_ID,
           T2.COD_IBGE,
           T4.BTS_ID;
```

Comment: can you post the full query being used? obviously you can't use `sum` inside another `sum`.

Comment: @vkp The query is extensive, added a part of it. I have several parts as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any sense regardless of database used. You group by eight columns, and for each group you compute `TAX_L` as a **SUM** of certain ratios from table `T1`. Then, for the same GROUPS, you want to count how many times <something> and `TAX_L >= 80`? The conditions should apply to each row individually; for a GROUP, that condition either is true or it is false for the group as a whole, not row by row. What is the query supposed to compute? (Just think about the columns and values related to your question.)

Comment: @mathguy This query compute equipment log. Overview per hour, accumulated. These values will generate monitoring indicators. I will remove the sums and deliver the clusters first, then the sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am totally unfamiliar with the construct you listed above, but I'm going to take a stab anyway since you can validate results from one system to the other.  My guess (and it's just a guess) is that you can achieve this result by using a CTE to get the first sum (`TAX_L`) and then use that value in the main query to get the over/under 80 values:

```
with yoda as (
  SELECT
    T4.FABR_ID, T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME, T3.DAY_OF_WEEK, T4.REGIONAL_ID,
    T4.UF_ID, T4.BSC_ID, T2.COD_IBGE, T4.BTS_ID,
    SUM (T1.M2251827) AS CAP_ALLOC,
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN T1.M2143831 > T1.M2460254
            THEN (T1.M2143831 * 100 / T1.M2143833)
          ELSE (T1.M2460254 * 100 / T1.M2460256)
        END) AS TAX_L,
    SUM (100 * T1.M2489212 / T1.M2489213) AS IUB_FRAME_LOST,
    SUM (T1.M1979632 * T1.M1979630) AS NUM_ACE,
    SUM (T1.M1977785 * T1.M1973189) AS DEN_ACE,
    SUM (T1.M2225994) AS THROUGHPUT_IUB_DOWNLINK_E,
    SUM ((T1.M2016166 + T1.M2016172 + T1.M1978319 + T1.M1978331)
          * 8 / 3600) AS THROUGHPUT_DADOS_TOTAL_H
  FROM
    DBN1.F_BTS T1,
    DBN1.DA_CADASTRO T2,
    DBN1.D_TIME T3,
    DBN1.D_ENTITY_BTS T4
  WHERE
    T2.AA_CADASTRO_KEY = T1.AA_CADASTRO_KEY
    AND T3.TIME_KEY = T1.TIME_KEY
    AND T4.ENTITY_KEY = T1.ENTITY_KEY
    AND T2.COD_IBGE <> -1
    AND T3.HOUR BETWEEN 08 AND 23
    AND T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME BETWEEN
      TO_DATE ('27-09-2016 08:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
      TO_DATE ('27-09-2016 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    AND T4.FABR_ID IN ('TEST1', 'TEST2')
    AND T4.BTS_ID NOT IN ('', '*, -1')
  GROUP BY
    T4.FABR_ID, T3.REPORT_DATE_TIME, T3.DAY_OF_WEEK, T4.REGIONAL_ID,
    T4.UF_ID, T4.BSC_ID, T2.COD_IBGE, T4.BTS_ID
)
select
  fabr_id, report_date_time, day_of_week, regional_id, uf_id, bsc_id,
  cod_ibge, bts_id, cap_alloc, tax_l, iub_frame_lost, num_ace,
  den_ace, throughput_uib_downlink_e, throughput_dados_total_h,
  SUM(CASE
        WHEN FABR_ID = 'TEST' AND TAX_L >= 80 THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
      END) AS OVER80,
  SUM(CASE
        WHEN FABR_ID = 'TEST' AND TAX_L < 80
          -- AND TAX_L IS NOT NULL  -- < 80 automatically means not null
          THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
      END) AS OVER80 -- you mean under 80?
from yoda
group by
  fabr_id, report_date_time, day_of_week, regional_id, uf_id, bsc_id,
  cod_ibge, bts_id, cap_alloc, tax_l, iub_frame_lost, num_ace,
  den_ace, throughput_uib_downlink_e, throughput_dados_total_h
```

Some miscellaneous observations.

1. The "else null" usually isn't necessary, but since we're on the topic did you mean "else 0"? instead?  1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + null + 1 = null
2. You had two columns aliased at "over 80."  I assumed one was "under"
3. FIELD > x, FIELD < x, FIELD != x all imply non-null values.  null is not > 80, < 80 and it's not NOT 80 [double not intended] (it's null).

Again, since I've never seen an aggregate referenced in the same portion of a query, my SQL above is an educated guess.

Comment: I was so focused that I forgot the WITH. This structure worked perfectly, made in two steps removed all NULL clauses, as you said, made no sense.
Thank you for your help.